# setVideoURI causes fatal signal 6(SIGABRT)

Tags: android, runtime-error

I'm testing an old app I created a while ago. The app is working on fiber WiFi, but if I use normal 3G connection the app crashes with a signal 6 VM error. I tried isolating the problem, I found out that it is caused by the setVideoURI method.

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (videourl != null && videourI != null
                && extracted.contains(".mp4")) {
            videoview.setOnPreparedListener(MainActivity.this);
            mc = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
            mc.setMediaPlayer(videoview);
            videoview.setVideoURI(videourI);
            videoview.start();
            save.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
      }
```

The problem seems to exist only on my Moto G with 4.4.4. Is this a known issue? And is there a workaround?

Comment: You should add stack trace with native bits as well.

Answer (score 1):

VideoView.setVideoURI() starts a new thread for media playback, but it is the media decoding part which causes extra delay. so try to run that method on seperate Thread.

```
if (videourl != null && videourI != null && extracted.contains(".mp4"))
{
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(MainActivity.this);
    mc = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoview);
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            videoview.setVideoURI(videourI);  // make videoView final
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    videoview.start();
                    save.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Now I get this error:     11-05 23:03:06.404: E/AndroidRuntime(4954): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()