# Android WEB RTC

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, webrtc

I am trying to implement Web Rtc in my android app for video chat but an error is showing up.

```
E/rtc: #
   # Fatal error in ../../webrtc/modules/audio_device/android/audio_manager.cc, line 77
   # Check failed: HasDeviceObjects()
   # 
   #
```

I have added dependencies in build.gradle and NDK support too.

> compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:9127@aar'

```
ndk {
        moduleName "my-module-name"
        cFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"
        ldLibs "log"
        stl "gnustl_shared"
        abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
    }
```

Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button cam1;
VideoRenderer videoRenderer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cam1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final PeerConnectionFactory peerConnectionFactory=new PeerConnectionFactory();
    PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(this, true, true, true, true);

    //Acquiring source info
    int  no_of_cams = VideoCapturerAndroid.getDeviceCount(); // no of sources
    final String sec_cam = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice(); // sec_cam name
    final String pri_cam = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfBackFacingDevice(); // pri_cam name
    final VideoCapturer capturer1 = VideoCapturerAndroid.create(sec_cam); //capturer for sec_cam
    final MediaConstraints videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
    final MediaConstraints audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();

    //creating GLSurface
    GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView=(GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.gl);
    //video renderer gui
    VideoRendererGui.setView(glSurfaceView,null);
    try {
        videoRenderer=VideoRendererGui.createGui(0,0,100,100,
                VideoRendererGui.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL,false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Front Cam Action
    cam1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // setting up tracks from sources
            VideoSource videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(capturer1,videoConstraints);
            VideoTrack  videoTrack  = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack(sec_cam, videoSource);
            AudioSource audioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints);
            AudioTrack  audioTrack  = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack(sec_cam,audioSource);
           // adding video to renderer
            videoTrack.addRenderer(videoRenderer);
            MediaStream mediaStream=peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream(sec_cam);
            mediaStream.addTrack(videoTrack);
            mediaStream.addTrack(audioTrack);
        }
    });}}
```

Comment: Where is that error happening? Can you put some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setVideoURI causes fatal signal 6(SIGABRT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616513/setvideouri-causes-fatal-signal-6sigabrt)

Answer (score 1):

call initializeAndroidGlobals first.

```
PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(this, true, true, true, true);
final PeerConnectionFactory peerConnectionFactory=new PeerConnectionFactory();
```